# Why is jQuery .text replacing the entire span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<p><input id="revenue" type="text" value="100000" /><span id="howmuch"><a href="" class="ka_button small_button small_cherry" target="_self" style="opacity: 1; "><span>How Much?</span></a></span></p>
<p id="howmuchpercent">You save <span id="savingspercent">$<span id="howmuchspan">23000.00</span>*</span></p>
```

And the following Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('span#howmuch a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var revenue = jQuery('input#revenue').val();
        var savingsonrevenue = revenue * 0.23;
        jQuery('span#howmuchspan').text(savingsonrevenue.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

When I click the `How Much?` button for some reason instead of replacing the contents of the `span#howmuchspan` it is replacing the entire span resulting in the following HTML

```
<span id="savingspercent">57500.00</span>
```

instead of

```
<span id="savingspercent">$<span id="howmuchspan">57000.00</span>*</span>
```

Comment: i usually use .html instead of .text   but i dont see how that could be the issue

Comment: Could you upload a demo of this? Also, `parseInt()` your `revenue` variable. It's a string, not a number.

Comment: Sidecomment: I think the 'span#howmuchspan' selector doesn't make much sense, you could simply have '#howmuchspan' since by the markup standard IDs should be unique.

Comment: Fyi, you only need to write `jQuery` once. The `ready` callback receives the global jQuery object as its first argument so you can do this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /* use $ here */ });`

Comment: Just of note.  It is not necessary to specify tagname when using ID selectors `jQuery('span#howmuchspan')` is just overkill you can simply use the following `jQuery('#howmuchspan')`

Comment: @Blender he doesn't need to parseInt since it is converted in the multiplication step.

Comment: It should work, which is why I'm confused... I must be missing something small somewhere.. Fresh eyes help... Could you take a look? probar.4tlc.info/benefits/savings (also on the calc with the slider, the price is not updating when a slide changes - it should as well, could you take a look?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have code somewhere else that's removing the contents of `savingspercent`. I created a jsFiddle using the code you posted, and it works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/sYA7j/

**EDIT**:

You have some similar code at the bottom of the page (lines 451-458). Remove it and you should be all set:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('span#howmuch a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var revenue = jQuery('input#revenue').val();
    var savingsonrevenue = revenue * 0.23;
    jQuery('p#howmuchpercent span').text(savingsonrevenue.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Created a jsFiddle to test it, and that is your problem. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/JDqBS/

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the gesture. Mike beat me to it, though ;)

Comment: It should work, which is why I'm confused... I must be missing something small somewhere.. Fresh eyes help... Could you take a look? http://probar.4tlc.info/benefits/savings/ (also on the calc with the slider, the price is not updating when a slide changes - it should as well, could you take a look?)

Comment: @tsdexter: Think I found your problem. You had some similar code towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this too and came back to post the answer... What I did was changed the header and footer files in the Wordpress Editor, however, when I FTP'd some changes it put the original header/footer back that still had the redundant js and css in it! Thanks for checking.. It all works now.

Answer (score 7):

I tried your code on JSFiddle, and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2FQ4X

Comment: It should work, which is why I'm confused... I must be missing something small somewhere.. Fresh eyes help... Could you take a look? probar.4tlc.info/benefits/savings (also on the calc with the slider, the price is not updating when a slide changes - it should as well, could you take a look?)

Comment: I'm not seeing the span getting overriden in that URL? using the "not sure of your numbers" box at the bottom does the same thing as the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the HTML markup in your project is like in example you specified? Might be unclosed tag or somthing.

Comment: I copied and pasted it from Chrome Web Inspector

Comment: This is borderline not an answer.